# CefSharp rendering issues

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp

I'm having issues at a customer with CefSharp rendering.
We also tried with the CefSharp.MinimalExample.Wpf.net472 without any changes.

The problem we are having is that the website is not rendering automatically.
On first load, the google page is loading. But when clicking or scrolling nothings happens.
Until an resize of the screen.
Any action, change of page does is not visualized until a resize.

When going from a window to maximize, the original page size is kept.

I made a video showing the issue: [Dropbox Transfer valid until 07/05/2024](https://www.dropbox.com/t/Ea1MeAUgSdghChnn)
This transfer also contains the full **debug.log**

CefSharp.Wpf 112.3.0 x64 build

First had issue in an 9x version embedded in our application.
Afterwards testing with the example with newest version.

Comment: Sounds like https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/3817

Comment: @amaitland thanks, exactly the issue! If you add as answer I will mark as solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Until an resize of the screen. Any action, change of page does is not visualized until a resize.

For those running **Intel Iris Xe Integration graphic cards** there is a bug in the **Intel** driver that causes `CefSharp` to stop redrawing. The bug isn't actually limited to `CefSharp`, anyone using a [WriteableBitmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) will have problems when using older Intel **drivers**.

The recommended solution is to upgrade to the last `Intel` drivers.
Alternatively you can fall back to [SoftwareOnly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.renderoptions.processrendermode?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) rendering in `WPF` to workaround the issue.

The relevant `WPF` issue is https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/3817